# psycopg2 Installation: ValueError: [u'path']

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

While attempting to install the Postgres driver for Django on my Windows 7 (64-bit) box, the process fails with a lot of output followed by this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall

raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: [u'path']
```

The installation command is

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Can you help me to understand and correct this error?

Full output is here: http://pastebin.com/BhLGe4Ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing [win-psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) instead of using pip to install psycopg2.